# Calculate timestamp with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need some assistance with setting up a php script that will redirect a user if their IP and timestamp is older then 20 minutes.

There may be a better way of doing this.  I have the page request working and that's dumping the IP Address and Datetime proeprly.  This is what I have pieced together so far with the validation:

```
// Check IP address and Time Stamp and block access if needed

 $query = "SELECT count(`id`) AS 'count'
       FROM `visits`
       WHERE 
         `client_ip` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'
         AND `submitted_time` > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-10 minutes'))."'
       LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($query));

if ($result['count'] > 0) {
 echo "You have already submitted within the last hour";}
 else
 {
 header("Location: control/index1.php");

  exit;
 }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Change your where to the following:

```
AND `submitted_time` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

No need to use PHP to get the current timestamp.

Comment: You can also use NOW(). They are one in the same. I personally feel like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP looks cleaner. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp